# R dealing with NULL values while converting list to matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix, data-conversion

Suppose I have a structure like the following:

```
data = structure(list(person = structure(list(name = "A, B", 
        gender = "F", dead = NULL), .Names = c("name", 
        "gender", "dead")), person = structure(list(name = "C", 
        gender = "M", dead = "RIP"), .Names = c("name", 
        "gender", "dead"))), .Names = c("person", "person"))
```

and I want to convert it into a matrix

```
data = matrix(unlist(data), nrow = length(data), ncol=length(data[[1]]), byrow = TRUE)
```

How do I avoid recycling the elements when using `matrix` or even before that using only the `base` functions without `plyr`'s `rbind.fill`?
The result is:

```
> data
     [,1]   [,2]  [,3]  
[1,] "A, B" "F"   "C"   
[2,] "M"    "RIP" "A, B"
```

and I would like to get `NA` or `""` where the value is `NULL`. For instance:

```
> data
     [,1]   [,2]  [,3]  
[1,] "A, B" "F"   ""   
[2,] "C"    "M"   "RIP"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the new `stri_list2matrix` function in the `stringi` package.

```
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(lapply(data, unlist), byrow=TRUE, fill="")
#      [,1]   [,2] [,3] 
# [1,] "A, B" "F"  ""   
# [2,] "C"    "M"  "RIP"
```

Or for `NA` instead of `""`, leave out the `fill` argument

```
stri_list2matrix(lapply(data, unlist), byrow=TRUE)
#      [,1]   [,2] [,3] 
# [1,] "A, B" "F"  NA   
# [2,] "C"    "M"  "RIP"
```

Or if you prefer a base R answer, to avoid problems you could make all vectors the same length first with `length<-`.  This will append `NA` to all shorter vectors and make them the same length of the longest vector.

```
len <- max(sapply(data, length)) ## get length of longest vector
t(sapply(unname(data), function(x) `length<-`(unname(unlist(x)), len)))
#      [,1]   [,2] [,3] 
# [1,] "A, B" "F"  NA   
# [2,] "C"    "M"  "RIP"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, that did the trick. I used the `base` version. Nicely done :] Now I saw your edit and you simplified it even more. Cheers!